# How to get part of pre trained model in Pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, autoencoder, torchvision

I have made an autoencoder model named `AutoEncoderNew()`, and after training, I want the encoder and the decoder part separately for some experiments on new samples.

The model class is as follows:

```
class AutoEncoderNew(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_nc, output_nc, num_downs, cond=0, ngf=32, norm_layer=nn.BatchNorm2d, use_dropout=False, n_blocks=9):
        assert(n_blocks >= 0)
        super(AutoEncoderNew, self).__init__()
        self.input_nc = input_nc
        self.output_nc = output_nc
        self.ngf = ngf
        self.cond = cond

        self.filters = []
        if type(norm_layer) == functools.partial:
            use_bias = norm_layer.func == nn.InstanceNorm2d
        else:
            use_bias = norm_layer == nn.InstanceNorm2d
        # ---
        # Maybe cut the model in half by using increments of 4?
        model01 = [nn.Conv2d(3, ngf*4, kernel_size=5, padding=2, stride=2,
                            bias=use_bias),
                  norm_layer(ngf*4),
                  nn.ReLU(0.2)]
        model02 = [nn.Conv2d(ngf*4, ngf*8, kernel_size=5,
                             stride=2, padding=2, bias=use_bias),
                   norm_layer(ngf*8),
                   nn.ReLU(0.2)]
        model03 = [nn.Conv2d(ngf*8, ngf*12, kernel_size=5,
                             stride=2, padding=2, bias=use_bias),
                   norm_layer(ngf*12),
                   nn.ReLU(0.2)]
        model03 += [nn.Conv2d(ngf*12, ngf*16, kernel_size=5,
                             stride=2, padding=2, bias=use_bias),
                   norm_layer(ngf*16),
                   nn.ReLU(0.2)]
        model04 = [nn.Conv2d(ngf*16, ngf*16, kernel_size=3,
                             stride=1, padding=1, bias=use_bias),
                   norm_layer(ngf*16),
                   nn.ReLU(0.2),
                   nn.MaxPool2d(2, stride=2),
                   norm_layer(ngf*16),
                   nn.ReLU(0.2)]
        model04 += [nn.Conv2d(ngf*16, ngf*12, kernel_size=3,
                             stride=1, padding=1, bias=use_bias),
                   norm_layer(ngf*12),
                   nn.ReLU(0.2),
                   nn.MaxPool2d(2, stride=2),
                   norm_layer(ngf*12),
                   nn.ReLU(0.2)]

        model2 = [nn.ConvTranspose2d(ngf*12, ngf*16, kernel_size=4,
                             stride=2, padding=1, bias=use_bias),
                   norm_layer(ngf*16),
                   nn.ReLU(True)]
        model2 += [nn.ConvTranspose2d(ngf*16, ngf*16, kernel_size=4,
                             stride=2, padding=1, bias=use_bias),
                   norm_layer(ngf*16),
                   nn.ReLU(True)]
        model2 += [nn.ConvTranspose2d(ngf*16, ngf*16, kernel_size=4,
                             stride=2, padding=1, bias=use_bias),
                   norm_layer(ngf*16),
                   nn.ReLU(True)]
        model2 += [nn.ConvTranspose2d(ngf*16, ngf*12, kernel_size=4,
                             stride=2, padding=1, bias=use_bias),
                   norm_layer(ngf*12),
                   nn.ReLU(True)]
        model2 += [nn.ConvTranspose2d(ngf*12, ngf*8, kernel_size=4,
                             stride=2, padding=1, bias=use_bias),
                   norm_layer(ngf*8),
                   nn.ReLU(True)]
        model2 += [nn.ConvTranspose2d(ngf*8, ngf*4, kernel_size=4,
                             stride=2, padding=1, bias=use_bias),
                   norm_layer(ngf*4),
                   nn.ReLU(True)]
        model2 += [nn.ConvTranspose2d(ngf*4, ngf, kernel_size=4,
                             stride=2, padding=1, bias=use_bias),
                   norm_layer(ngf),
                   nn.ReLU(True)]
        model2 += [nn.Conv2d(ngf, 3, kernel_size=4,
                             stride=2, padding=1, bias=use_bias),
                   nn.Tanh()]  

        self.model01 = nn.Sequential(*model01)
        self.model02 = nn.Sequential(*model02)
        self.model03 = nn.Sequential(*model03)
        self.model04 = nn.Sequential(*model04)
        self.model2 = nn.Sequential(*model2)

    def forward(self, x, cond=0):
        #Reconstruction Only
        if self.cond == 0:
            enc = self.model04(self.model03(self.model02(self.model01(x))))
            dec = self.model2(enc)
            return dec
        #Encode Only
        if self.cond == 1:
            enc = self.model04(self.model03(self.model02(self.model01(x))))
            return enc
        #Decoder Only
        if self.cond == 2:
            dec = self.model2(x)
            return dec
        #Pixel_features
        if self.cond == 3:
            f01 = self.model01(x)
            f02 = self.model02(f01)
            f03 = self.model03(f02)
            f04 = self.model04(f03)
            return f01, f02, f03, f04
```

Here I make use of the `cond` variable value to get the encoder and decoder as follows:

```
encoder = AutoEncoderNew(3,3,2,1) # cond=1 for encoder
encoder.load_state_dict(auto_model.state_dict())
```

Is this the correct way to go about it? Is there anything wrong with this approach?

Answer (score 0):

Without going on into your code, i'll briefly explain in general, with kind of a psuedo code. My syntax is obviously not correct. Hope you get the idea

```
class AutoEncoderNew(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        self.Encoder = nn.Sequential(Conv2d,Norm,Relu,...,Conv2d,Norm,Relu)
        self.Decoder = nn.Sequential(ConvTranspose2d,Norm,Relu,...,ConvTranspose2d,Norm,Relu)

    def forward(x,self):
        encoded_x = Encoder(x)
        decoded_x = Decoder(encoded_x)
        return decoded_x
```

later when u load your model

```
autencoder = AutoEncoder() 
autoencoder.load_state_dict(auto_model.state_dict())
```

you can now call a specific block in your loaded model  as follow:

```
encoder = autoencoder.Encoder
decoder = autoencoder.Decoder
```